# Haskell - Preorder Numbering of Tree

Tags: haskell, preorder

I'm preparing for my exam from nonprocedural languages. I have example of test task and I don't know how to solve it.

Task is following:

Given two tree structures:

```
data Tree a = Nil1 | Node1 a [Tree a]
data NumTree a  = Nil2 | Node2 (a,Int) [NumTree a]
```

write function

```
numberTree :: Num a => Tree a -> NumTree a
```

which will return numbered `NumTree a` in preorder.

I tried this, but don't know how to continue.

```
numberTree tree = numberTree' tree 1

numberTree' :: Num a => Tree a -> Int -> NumTree a
numberTree' Nil1 _ = Nil2
numberTree' (Node1 num list) x = (Node2 (num,x) (myMap x numberTree list))
```

I dont know how to write something like this `myMap`,because it should return tree and the acumulated preorder number, but i don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't see why you need the `Num a` constraint.

Comment: I think your helper function should have the type `numberTree' :: Tree a -> Int -> (NumTree a, Int)`.

Comment: thanks but i think it is `numberTree' :: Tree a -> Int -> NumTree a` or not?

Comment: and `Num a` it is becouse in the tree will be Nums

Comment: Your `numberTree` function shouldn't care about the tree elements, it should just add numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for the `State` monad, which takes care of threading the value used to number each node through the recursive calls that visit each node.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

data Tree a = Nil1 | Node1 a [Tree a] deriving (Show)
data NumTree a = Nil2 | Node2 (a,Int) [NumTree a] deriving (Show)

numberTree :: Tree a -> NumTree a
numberTree Nil1 = Nil2
numberTree tree = evalState (numberTree' tree) 0

-- The state stores the value used to number the root
-- of the current tree. Fetch it with get, and put back
-- the number to use for the next root.
-- numberTree' is then used to number each child tree
-- in order before returning a new NumTree value.

numberTree' :: Tree a -> State Int (NumTree a)
numberTree' Nil1 = return Nil2
numberTree' (Node1 root children) = do rootNum <- get
                                       put (rootNum + 1)
                                       newChildren <- mapM numberTree' children
                                       return (Node2 (root, rootNum) newChildren)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solution. It seems to be working, but in my ghci is not `State` monad. How it is implemented?

Comment: @Vojacejo try https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Control.Monad.State

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) here to your advantage:

> *The `mapAccumL` function behaves like a combination of `map` and `foldl`; it applies a function to each element of a list, passing an accumulating parameter from left to right, and returning a final value of this accumulator together with the new list.*

Looking at the types, trying to connect the matching wires, main function would then look something like

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)

data Tree a = Nil1 | Node1 a [Tree a]  deriving Show
data NumTree a  = Nil2 | Node2 (a,Int) [NumTree a] deriving Show

numberTree :: Tree a -> NumTree a
numberTree tree = tree2
   where
   (_, [tree2]) = mapAccumL g 1 [tree]
   g n Nil1 = (n, Nil2)
   g n (Node1 x trees) = (z, Node2 (x,n) trees2)
      where
      (z, trees2) = ....
```

> mapAccumL g (n+1) trees

There's no need for the `Num a =>` constraint. You don't visit the nodes' values, you just count the nodes regardless of what they carry:

> > numberTree (Node1 1.1 [Node1 2.2 [ Node1 3.3 [], Nil1], Node1 4.4 [] ]) 
>   Node2 (1.1,1) [Node2 (2.2,2) [Node2 (3.3,3) [],Nil2],Node2 (4.4,4) []]